# How to redirect a hybrid application to home page instead of tutorial page in Ionic ios application?

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

Currently i am developing an Hybrid application using ionic. So my application normally contains an intro view and after the intro view it goes straight to the home page. When i kill the application i need to show the home page instead of tutorial view while launching again. Since i am a native iOS developer i am pretty clear about managing it in the native ios code like this:

```
        func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("login") == nil)
        {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "login")
        }
        if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("login") == true)
        {

            do {
                let arr1 = try UserProfileDataHelper.find("1")
                if arr1?.Type == "Customer" {
                    currentUser = "Customer"
                    screenlaunch("MENU")
                }else{
                    currentUser = "Store"
                    screenlaunch("HOME")
                }

            } catch _{}


        }

         return true
    }

 func screenlaunch(str : String )
    {
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

            let homeViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(str)
            let navigationController :UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeViewController)
            navigationController.navigationBarHidden = true
            window!.rootViewController = nil
            window!.rootViewController = navigationController
            window?.makeKeyWindow()

    }
```

How to achieve the same in the ionic application . Please have an idea on this. After my research i found that my fellow old colleague had made use of:

```
   console.log("didTutorial: "+$localStorageProvider.get('didTutorial'));
  if( $localStorageProvider.get('didTutorial') ){

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/hero');
  }
  else{

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  }
```

Is it something related to state change?

[image: ScreenShots]

Answer (score 1):

You can use below concept of loading Root page based on condition.

As per your requirement first time you need to load Tutorial Page Navigation flow and on 2nd load you don't need Tutorial page as first page.

So for that do as mention below.

**Step1:** Add one variable `rootPage: any;` in your `app.component.ts` page.

**Step2:** Bind that **rootPage** in your `app.html` file where it deside which root page will be load at startup of your app.

```
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

**Step3:** Now in your `app.component.ts` page check condition that Tutorial page seen by user or not and based on that assign **rootPage** like below.

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      //retrieve isAppRunFirstTime from DB storage 

      if (!isAppRunFirstTime) {
          this.rootPage = TutorialPage;
      } else {
          this.rootPage = HomePage;
       }
    }
  }
```

> Note : `isAppRunFirstTime` is flag which decide your app is loading at
>   first time.

above flag you can store in Storage DB and at first time app load make it True in your DB.

Hope this will help you to load conditional root page in your app.

Comment: isAppRunFirstTime can i store it in localstorage? I am not using any db here :)

Comment: console.log("didTutorial: "+$localStorageProvider.get('didTutorial'));
  if( $localStorageProvider.get('didTutorial') ){

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/hero');
  }
  else{

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
One more thing when i kill the application and launch the app again it goes in to the if loop rather than else loop so why not it is being directed to '/app/hero' ? please do tell

Comment: '/app/hero' is my home page.

Comment: Yes you can store it into localstorage

Comment: this.rootPage = hero; use this will load your home page.

Comment: where to find app.component.ts file? Do i need to create it new?

Comment: its available in your scr/app/app.component.ts

Comment: sorry i cannot find scr/app/app.component.ts. I have attached screenshot of my folder listing. Please see :)

Comment: I am using ionic1 thats why i don't have src folder. Thanks for the help. It will be a great help if you help me for ionic1 version.
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/missing-app-module-ts-and-src-app-folders/90207